# SAP B1 HANA: Error: -8031 Unable to retrieve OBSERVERDLL.dll from server

Tags: sapb1

When I use DI API: connect to SAP BUSINESS ONE HANA 9.3 PL13, I'm get error: -8031 Unable to retrieve OBSERVERDLL.dll from server.

Plz help me!

Comment: Try clearing your %TEMP% folder (specifically the SM_OBS_DLL folder if you have one).

Comment: Make sure you are using the right DI API version for 9.3 PL 13. I actually run this version of SAP.